# fatal error: 'fst/types.h' file not found

Tags: python, c++, anaconda

I'm trying to install `openfst` like so:

```
wget http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/FST/FstDownload/openfst-1.8.2.tar.gz
tar zxvf openfst-1.8.2.tar.gz
cd openfst-1.8.2
./configure --enable-python
make
sudo make install
```

but during the Python installation step, I get:

```
Making install in python
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=c++17 -fno-exceptions -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./../../include -I/Users/colin/opt/miniconda3/envs/logos/include/python3.8  -fexceptions -g -O2 -MT pywrapfst_la-pywrapfst.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/pywrapfst_la-pywrapfst.Tpo -c -o pywrapfst_la-pywrapfst.lo `test -f 'pywrapfst.cpp' || echo './'`pywrapfst.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=c++17 -fno-exceptions -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I./../../include -I/Users/colin/opt/miniconda3/envs/logos/include/python3.8 -fexceptions -g -O2 -MT pywrapfst_la-pywrapfst.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/pywrapfst_la-pywrapfst.Tpo -c pywrapfst.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/pywrapfst_la-pywrapfst.o
pywrapfst.cpp:643:10: fatal error: 'fst/types.h' file not found
#include <fst/types.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I don't really understand why, given that seemingly we just installed the necessary `fst` components?

Is this an issue with the conda installation or something else?

I'm using Miniconda with conda version 4.13.0

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not `sudo apt install libfst-dev`?

Comment: OpenFst is available [as a conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openfst)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the openfst itself:
[OpenFst no longer produces a fst/types.h](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/issues/4712)

If you just want to use wrapped python or not a C++ dev, you should use anaconda package: [OpenFST anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openfst) as @kotatsuyaki suggest. Or you can install from source with version 1.7.x